# In IntelliJ IDEA CTRL+SHIFT+F9 results in : Cannot package file IO Error: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset

Tags: java, intellij-idea

when I do CTRL+SHIFT+F9 (to recompile) on any of my XHTML files it triggers 'packaging files', which takes fare longer then normal. Normally it takes a few seconds, but now the takes more then 30 seconds and ends with a Cannot package file IO Error: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset

No build problem.

I used IntelliJ from a long time and never faced this issue before.

Note: I have tried invalidating cache.

IntelliJ Logs::

```
java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:589)
at com.intellij.util.io.zip.JBZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(JBZipFile.java:375)
at com.intellij.util.io.zip.JBZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(JBZipFile.java:229)
at com.intellij.util.io.zip.JBZipFile.<init>(JBZipFile.java:126)
at com.intellij.util.io.zip.JBZipFile.<init>(JBZipFile.java:83)
at com.intellij.packaging.impl.ui.actions.PackageFileWorker.getOrCreateZipFile(PackageFileWorker.java:198)
at com.intellij.packaging.impl.ui.actions.PackageFileWorker.packFile(PackageFileWorker.java:162)
at com.intellij.packaging.impl.ui.actions.PackageFileWorker.copyFile(PackageFileWorker.java:150)
at com.intellij.packaging.impl.ui.actions.PackageFileWorker.packageFile(PackageFileWorker.java:128)
at com.intellij.packaging.impl.ui.actions.PackageFileWorker.packageFile(PackageFileWorker.java:117)
at com.intellij.packaging.impl.ui.actions.PackageFileWorker$1.lambda$run$0(PackageFileWorker.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.lambda$run$1(ReadAction.java:53)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:936)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:57)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.run(ReadAction.java:53)
at com.intellij.packaging.impl.ui.actions.PackageFileWorker$1.run(PackageFileWorker.java:83)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:408)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: You should contact IntelliJ about this.

Comment: There is already a question posted on (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177017)  which I think is intellij forum and got no reply.

Comment: Then you should try to reactivate that issue. We can't help much with an internal unfixed bug.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the solution.**
After trying for long I found there is some issue in IntelliJ (not a code issue nor any issue with a particular IntelliJ version ), something in IntelliJ generated files may-be.

The way around was to set-up a fresh project.

If anyone finds out the proper solution please post it here so many can get benefited.

Answer (score 0):

After my computer crash.I have the same problem.
I think the problem was caused by system crash when IDEA was editing the configuration file.
The solution is to delete all configuration files of IDEA(not your project's file) and then re-import the project .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).